# e.preventDefault() and e.cancelBubble not working with attached listeners

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm attempting to disable links clicked. I have an `onmousedown` event listener attached as such.

```
if(document.addEventListener){
    document.addEventListener("onmouseover", onMouseOverIdent, false);
    document.addEventListener("onmousedown", onMouseDownIdent, false);
    document.addEventListener("onmouseout", onMouseOutIdent, false);
}else{
    if(document.attachEvent){
        document.attachEvent("onmousedown",onMouseDownIdent);
        document.attachEvent("onmouseover",onMouseOverIdent);
        document.attachEvent("onmouseout", onMouseOutIdent);
    }
}
```

In my `onmousedown` function I tried using this function from quirksmode:

```
if (!e) var e = window.event;
e.cancelBubble = true;
if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
```

However it will still do click through to the link and load it. I have not idea what could be causing it and any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
One other thing I forgot to mention is I'm doing this on all anchor tag elements on the page. This seems to be making it more problematic to remove those listeners afterwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make it so the href isn't followed, you should be using `preventDefault` instead  of `stopPropagation`.

For IE, you'd use

```
e.returnValue = false;
```

So it should look like this...

```
if (!e) var e = window.event;
e.returnValue = false;
if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
```

---

This assumes that the handler is directly on the link, which can't be known right now since you've excluded relevant code.

---

One more thing, you're only working with the `onmousedown` event. If you want to prevent the behavior or disable the bubbling of the actual `click` event, you should be doing...

```
document.addEventListener("click", ...
document.attachEvent("onclick", ...
```

Also, notice that `addEventListener` should *not* have `"on"` as part of the event name.

Comment: So this is interesting. I tried this in my onmousedown event and it didn't work but creating a new even listener separately on the anchor tags, seems to work. Why does it have to be on the link specifically? Does e.returnValue prevent the bubbling from occurring while propagation doesn't?

Comment: @crtjer: I'm having to make some assumptions because you didn't include the relevant code in your question. I assumed the handler was on the `<a>` element. There are other issues too, so I updated my answer.

Comment: yes this is on every anchor element on the page. The problem I'm running into now is adding these in a loop. I'm getting all the elementsbytagname and then trying to add the listeners. I realize I have to use an anonymous function but then removing afterwards is causing a problem.

Comment: @crtjer: Why do you have to use an anonymous function?

Comment: I'm looping through the elements. When I tried doing a normal function call and calling it on each anchor in the loop it wasn't getting hit t all.